# Export excel spreadsheet to XML and sort array alphabetically during or after export?

Tags: xml, excel, sorting, xslt

We have an excel document with hundreds of fields mapped to an XML and a macro that exports the data, across a dozen tabs, to XML which is used for composition of a communication. Everything is working fine, but now they would like some of the data to be sorted alphabetically.

They want to avoid having a macro run a sort on the tables that are mapped to arrays elements. So we were wondering if we could have the data sorted during/after the export without using another application to run an XSLT. Can this done as part of the excel export?

Below is some sample data:

How the data exports

```
<Grid>
   <Funds>
      <Name>Company C 2010</Name>
      <Symbol>TCON10</Symbol>
      <Replacement>New C 2010</Replacement>
      <ReplacementSymbol>CPN10</ReplacementSymbol>
   </Fund>
   <Funds>
      <Name>Company B 2020</Name>
      <Symbol>TCON20</Symbol>
      <Replacement>New B 2020</Replacement>
      <ReplacementSymbol>CPN20</ReplacementSymbol>
   </Fund>
   <Funds>
      <Name>Company A 2030</Name>
      <Symbol>TCON30</Symbol>
      <Replacement>New A 2030</Replacement>
      <ReplacementSymbol>CPN30</ReplacementSymbol>
   </Fund>
</Grid>
```

How they would like the data to look (alphabetically sorting on the field )

```
<Grid>
   <Funds>
      <Name>Company A 2030</Name>
      <Symbol>TCON30</Symbol>
      <Replacement>New A 2030</Replacement>
      <ReplacementSymbol>CPN30</ReplacementSymbol>
   </Fund>
   <Funds>
     <Name>Company B 2020</Name>
     <Symbol>TCON20</Symbol>
     <Replacement>New B 2020</Replacement>
     <ReplacementSymbol>CPN20</ReplacementSymbol>
   </Fund>
   <Funds>
     <Name>Company C 2010</Name>
     <Symbol>TCON10</Symbol>
     <Replacement>New C 2010</Replacement>
     <ReplacementSymbol>CPN10</ReplacementSymbol>
   </Fund>
</Grid>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure can. Using the [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, you can run XSLT transformation inside VBA. Either you can embed XSLT inside as a VBA string (if contains no URL) using `LoadXML()` or as a separate file using `Load()`.

Below is the separate file route:

**XSLT** (save as external .xsl)

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <!-- IdentityTransform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Grid">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Funds">
        <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**VBA Macro**

```
Dim xmldoc As Object, xsldoc As Object, newdoc As Object

Set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set xsldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set newdoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

' LOAD XML
xmldoc.async = False
xmldoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Original.xml"  

' LOAD XSL
xsldoc.async = False
xsldoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\XSLT_File.xsl"

' TRANSFORM
xmldoc.transformNodeToObject xsldoc, newdoc
newdoc.Save ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output.xml"
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid>
    <Funds>
        <Name>Company A 2030</Name>
        <Symbol>TCON30</Symbol>
        <Replacement>New A 2030</Replacement>
        <ReplacementSymbol>CPN30</ReplacementSymbol>
    </Funds>
    <Funds>
        <Name>Company B 2020</Name>
        <Symbol>TCON20</Symbol>
        <Replacement>New B 2020</Replacement>
        <ReplacementSymbol>CPN20</ReplacementSymbol>
    </Funds>
    <Funds>
        <Name>Company C 2010</Name>
        <Symbol>TCON10</Symbol>
        <Replacement>New C 2010</Replacement>
        <ReplacementSymbol>CPN10</ReplacementSymbol>
    </Funds>
</Grid>
```

**NOTE**: Your tags are off with `<Funds>` opening and `<Fund>` closing. Check if this is just a typo here on SO or your original code is rendering a not well-formed XML.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Yeah the <Funds> tag is a typo when I was creating Faux data to represent what I was trying to do. Cheers

Comment: I am getting stuck with:     xmldoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Original.xml". Due to the export of the XML that will require sorting will have a variable file name (using a time stamp) I will not know what the file name will be in order to tell VBA to load it. I will work on it. Thanks again